# Input to reshape is a tensor with 788175 values, but the requested shape has 1050900

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am importing in some arrays of data to train on but tensorflow is outputting below error.

```
inp = open('train.csv',"rb")
X = pickle.load(inp)
X = X/255.0
X = np.array(X)
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(113, 75, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(75, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(75, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(25425, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
    keras.layers.Reshape((113, 75, 4))
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, X, epochs=5)
```

I should be able to create an autoencoder but the program outputs this:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\dalto\Documents\geo4\train.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.fit(X, X, epochs=5)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 643, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 664, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 383, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3510, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 572, in __call__
    return self._call_flat(args)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 671, in _call_flat
    outputs = self._inference_function.call(ctx, args)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 445, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 788175 values, but the requested shape has 1050900
     [[node reshape/Reshape (defined at C:\Users\dalto\Documents\geo4\train.py:24) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_922]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

If I change the Reshape to (113, 75, 3) I get this it doesn't fix the error it just changes it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dalto\Documents\geo4\train.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.fit(X, X, epochs=5)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 643, in fit
use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 664, in fit
steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 383, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3510, in __call__
outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 572, in __call__
return self._call_flat(args)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 671, in _call_flat
outputs = self._inference_function.call(ctx, args)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 445, in call
ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\dalto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible 
shapes: [31,113,75] vs. [31,113,75,3]
 [[node metrics/accuracy/Equal (defined at 
C:\Users\dalto\Documents\geo4\train.py:24) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_922]
```

Comment: Input shape is `(113,75,3)`. Output is `(113,75,4)`. Fixing this probably helps.

Comment: It gives me a completely different error.

Comment: if you reshape the output to [x,y,z] then `x*y*z` must be equal to the previous layer size. in your case `25425 != 113*745*4 = 33900`. @user2653663 is right, use `(113,75,3)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input and output size after reshape must be same. So, you'll have to use `(113, 75, 3)` instead of `(113, 75, 4)`.

Now, by using `(113, 75, 3)`, you're getting the unequal error because you're using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as your loss function, you should instead use `categorical_crossentropy`.

The basic difference between these is that `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` works when you have direct integers as your label, and `categorical_crossentropy` works when you have one-hot encoded labels.

**Corrected:**

```
inp = open('train.csv',"rb")
X = pickle.load(inp)
X = X/255.0
X = np.array(X)
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(113, 75, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(75, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(75, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(25425, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
    keras.layers.Reshape((113, 75, 4))
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, X, epochs=5)
```